# Unable to detect Intel's X540 network controller

Tags: networking, drivers, server, ethernet

Just got my hands on a [Gigabyte MD80-TM0](http://b2b.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5146#sp) motherboard to help run my Ubuntu Server.

During the hardware detection process of the Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 (and 15.10) installation it reported that “No network interfaces detected”. Despite the fact the network cable plugged into the motherboard’s LAN port was showing solid colours indicating it had identified at a 1Gbps data rate and the BIOS showed MAC addresses for both LAN ports.

As far as I can tell the on board LAN ports are handled by Intel’s X540 chipset which I believe should be supported as part of the default installation.

Finishing the installation allowed me to specifically add “ixgbe” to the end of /etc/modules which had no effect. Further diagnostic commands show only a Local Loopback interface:

```
sudo ifconfig -a
lo  Link encap:Local Loopback
    inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
    RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelan:0
    RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB) TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)

cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

ls /sys/class/net
lo
```

The following commands return nothing

```
sudo lshw -C network
dmesg | grep -e eth0
lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2
```

If I need to update my drivers I will need to buy a separate [PCIe Network Card](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/tp-link-gigabit-pci-express-pci-e-network-interface-card-n34nt) that has a good compatibility with Linux to allow me to download the necessary packages to install the drivers. Before I spend any money I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something silly.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, the command returned nothing, you can see the full output of `lspci -nnk` here http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/15527845/

Comment: We see no network or ethernet devices whatever. Is there a setting in the BIOS to enable/disable LAN devices? Please check.

Comment: As far as I can tell all settings related to the on-board LAN controller are enabled. Here are screen shots to show the settings I found http://postimg.org/gallery/37eff0f5s/894f2a6c/ (Can't add screenshots to my question). I am currently accessing the server via its management LAN via a KVM client.

Comment: The same problem existed after installing Windows Server 2012 R2 and the network drivers couldn't detect any Intel Adapters so will try again with a new Motherboard.

Comment: Turns out the on-board network control doesn't work when only one out of the two CPUs are installed. Should I delete this question since it relates to a hardware issue rather than a Ubuntu one or should I just answer it myself?

Comment: Please answer it yourself for the benefit of the searchers. I'm glad it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the motherboard has a sneaky clause in its [documentation](http://b2b.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5146#sp) stating "If only 1 CPU is installed, some PCIe, memory, network or I/O functions will not be available." which translates to the network controller will not work if you only have 1 CPU installed.